# aws s3 metadata all keys

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

The only way to read the user-defined metadata on an s3 object it seems is using head-object.

`AWS_PROFILE=development aws s3api head-object --bucket "xxx-development" --key 'my-object-key'`

s3api list-objects let's you get all the objects in the bucket including being able to filter for required patterns in the keys using --query, but it doesn't give the user-defined metadata associated with those objects.

`AWS_PROFILE=development aws s3api list-objects --bucket "xxx-development" --query 'Contents[?contains(Key, 'original')]'`

Is there a way to get all the objects and associated user-defined metadata without enumerating all the objects and iterating through all of them and doing a head-object on each?

user-defined metadata keys help us categorize our uploads to give meaningful insights.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, no. The [GET Bucket (List Objects) Version 2](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/v2-RESTBucketGET.html) (as well as Version 1) do not return user-defined metadata for an object.

You'll have to use `HEAD object` on each object returned by `GET Bucket`.

Comment: Thanks. Yes that's the current approach I am thinking of.
I am assuming that would be the most efficient approach?

Comment: Yes, your solution is the most efficient. The other possible solution would be to use  `GET Object` instead of `HEAD Object`, but that would be less efficient in terms response size.

Comment: You would definitely want to stick with `HEAD` for this purpose.  @Jay the alternative I use is I have Lambda triggers on `PUT` for the bucket.  These invoke node.js code that does the`HEAD` request and stores the metadata in RDS/MariaDB, fully normalized and indexed for proper querying.

Comment: Thanks Michael. That's a great tip. We have already add something akin to that for future. We push useful stats as cloudwatch metrics and datadog gives a good interface to plot and look at the metrics.
But I like the idea of pushing it to a DB, where I can partition the data and associate properties with individual assets for re-processing files in a batch if required in future.